# How to find specific number in a string php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have different strings in which I want to find specific number. If the number is within the string it should print that number.

Strings are like these:

```
string(9) "path_12.0" 
string(9) "path_12.1" 
string(9) "path_13.0" 
string(9) "path_13.1" 
string(9) "path_13.2"
```

Numbers are like:

```
int(12) 
int(12) 
int(13) 
int(13) 
int(13)
```

What I tried is:

```
if (strpos(','.$mainString.',' , ','.$QuestionId.',') != FALSE) { 
        echo $QuestionId;
} // this doesn't print anything in the body
```

I also tried the below trick but it also doesn't print anything

```
if(in_array($QuestionId, explode(',', $mainString))) {
    echo $QuestionId;
}
```

I want to check something like this:

```
if($questionId is in $mainString) { 
      echo $questionId;
}
```

**Note:** I searched similar questions on StackOverflow but I didn't found a solution which solved my issue, therefore I'm posting this question.

Comment: So you want to check if 12 is in the first and second string, and 13 in the last 3 strings? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @Qirel I'm looping through all strings so definitely I want to check the `questionId` in all strings.

Comment: Given your example, `strpos(','.$mainString.',' , ','.$QuestionId.',')` will provide `strpos(',path_12.0,' , ',12,')` You won't find it

Comment: what's the point of the commas around the strings ?

Comment: @Cid just followed a stackoverflow answer:)

Comment: Like @Cid said, commas are not usefull. Use `strpos($mainString, $QuestionId.'.')` should result in  `strpos('path_12.0' , '12.')`

Comment: @Iftikharuddin Does my solution solve your problem?

Comment: Does the `$mainString` is 'path_12.0'? Or an array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below snippet,

```
$paths = ["path_12.0", "path_12.1", "path_13.0", "path_13.1", "path_13.2", ];
$nos = [12, 12, 13, 13, 13, ];
function strpos_arr($needle,$haystack)
{
    if (!is_array($haystack)) {
        $haystack = [$haystack];
    }
    foreach ($haystack as $what) {
        if (($pos = strpos($what,(string)$needle)) !== false) {
            return $pos;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
foreach ($nos as $key => $value) {
    // checking if question id in in path array with str pos
    if(strpos_arr($value,$paths) !== false){
        echo $value."\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/B0tSb).

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be to create an array with your strings and use [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) with a pattern that checks if the first part of the decimal is equal of one of the numbers.

Example of [a pattern](https://regex101.com/r/QMZ9yz/1) where the digits from the array are used as an alternation:

```
_\K(?:12|13)(?=\.\d+)
```

- `_\K` Match underscore and forget what was matched
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `12|13` Match either 12 or 13
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(?=\.\d+)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is a dot and 1+ digits

For example:

```
$numbers = [12, 13];
$strings = [
    "path_12.0",
    "path_12.1",
    "path_13.0",
    "path_13.1",
    "path_13.2",
    "path_14.1"
];

$pattern = "/_\K(?:" . implode('|', $numbers) . ")(?=\.\d+)/";
$resullt = preg_grep($pattern, $strings);
print_r($resullt);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => path_12.0
    [1] => path_12.1
    [2] => path_13.0
    [3] => path_13.1
    [4] => path_13.2
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/tTNIn)

Or if you want to print the numbers only, you might use [array_reduce](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-reduce.php) and collect the matches:

```
$result = array_reduce($strings, function($carry, $item) use ($pattern){
    if (preg_match($pattern, $item, $matches)){
        $carry[] = $matches[0];

    }
    return $carry;
});

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 13
    [4] => 13
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/cV4BM)

Answer (score 2):

```
$array_strings =  ["path_12.0", "path_12.1", "path_13.0", "path_13.1", "path_13.2"];
$array_numbers = [12, 22, 13, 11, 17];
$results = [];

foreach ($array_strings as $string){
  preg_match_all('!\d+\.*\d*!', $string, $matches);
  foreach ($array_numbers as $number){
      if (in_array($number, $matches[0])){
             array_push($results, $number);
         }
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

**results:** `Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 13 )`


**Note 1:**  array answers can have duplicate values.